# WPF Animate and change Opacity of Image in sequence

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, opacity

I have three images, two of these images animate as follow and third image should blink:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="AnimateTarget" RepeatBehavior="Forever">

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:00:03" Storyboard.TargetName="img1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0" />
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="200" />
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:2" Duration="0:00:03" Storyboard.TargetName="img2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="x">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0" />
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="200" />
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:4" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="img3"  From="1.0" To="0.0" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" />

    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

The first two images are animating fine but the third image doesn’t blink, it will do nothing and just stay there as you can see I have used the following code for blinking the third image:

```
<DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:4" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="img3"  From="1.0" To="0.0" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" />
```

Also this is a code for the third image:

```
<Image Height="65" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="67" Source="/PicTakeWPF;component/Images/422505_110594629067212_100003500265268_37406_1212153553_n.jpg">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
         <TranslateTransform x:Name="img3"></TranslateTransform>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

I would appreciate if someone helps me on this
Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the Name (image1) of your image object as Storyboard.TargetName for the opacity animation

```
<DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:4" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1"  From="1.0" To="0.0" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" />
```

because the opacity is a property of the image itself, the other 2 animations affect the translation of the image object and that's why you use the TranslateTransform name for those animations.

You don't even need to add

```
<Image.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform x:Name="img3"></TranslateTransform>
</Image.RenderTransform>
```

for the third image (if you're not planning on animating the translation).