# Can't set image Opactity Property

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have this Image:

```xaml
<Image x:Name="imgOsuLogo" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="205" Source="{Binding Logo}">
```

And this code behind to animate the Image:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        imgOsuLogo.DataContext = workingResources;
        imgOsuLogo.Opacity = 0;
        txbUpdate.DataContext = workingResources;

        GetSongName();
        GetSkinInfo();

        Task task = new Task(() => 
        {

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(FadeInBlackBackGround);

        });
        Task task2 = new Task(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(6000);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(MainOsu);
        });
        task.Start();
        task2.Start();
    }

    private void MainOsu()
    {

        BlackCurtain.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        imgOsuLogo.Opacity = 1;
    }

    private void FadeInBlackBackGround()
    {  
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        BlackCurtain.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animation);
        DoubleAnimation animationLogo = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        imgOsuLogo.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animationLogo);
    }
```

When the line `imgOsuLogo.Opacity = 1;` in `MainOsu` Method executes, the Opacity Property not change to 1, even when I try to change it in Visual Studio Debugger.

Comment: Note that you don't need the Tasks. Just set the animation's BeginTime and add a Completed handler that does whatever is necessary. If you'd explain how it is supposed to work, we might provide a much less complicated solution.

Comment: I using task to make the window responeable while the thread.Sleep(3000) is excute

Comment: Your primary problem however is that the default FillBehavior of a DoubleAnimation is `HoldEnd`, i.e. it retains the end value forever. Change it to `Stop`.

Comment: While a delay isn't necessary at all (because you can set an animation's BeginTime), it's also better to use Task.Delay instead of Thread.Sleep.

Comment: @QuanVN : Check if this SO answer helps you:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146833/885920

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active animations have higher [value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) than local values. To solve this, you would have to either change the animation's `FillBehavior` or cancel/override the animation manually, e.g.:

```
imgOsuLogo.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, null);
```

From MSDN:

> **Active animations, or animations with a Hold behavior**.
>   In order to have any practical effect, an animation of a property must be able to have precedence over the base (unanimated) value, even if that value was set locally.

Comment: Thanks you this work perfectly, just ask you code before the img.Opacity

`private void MainOsu()
        {
            
            BlackCurtain.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            imgOsuLogo.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, null); //Add this
            imgOsuLogo.Opacity = 1;
        }`

Comment: You are welcome. *"just ask you code before the img.Opacity"* The exact order shouldn't really matter - as soon as the animation is removed, the local value should kick in. The last value you set manually is (as far as I can see) `0`, so you should keep the `Opacity = 1` line. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yeah, I should keep the `Opacity = 1` line

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand the question, you want to start both animations after 3 seconds, and after 6 seconds make BlackCurtain disappear and set the Image's Opacity back to 1.

This should do everything without any Task or timer:

```
BlackCurtain.Opacity = 0;
var a1 = new DoubleAnimation
{
    From = 0,
    To = 3,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
    BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
    FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
};
a1.Completed += (s, e) => BlackCurtain.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
BlackCurtain.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, a1);

var a2 = new DoubleAnimation
{
    From = 1,
    To = -2,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
    BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
    FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
};
a1.Completed += (s, e) => imgOsuLogo.Opacity = 1;
imgOsuLogo.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, a2);
```

Comment: @QuanVN Sure, but this one is simpler :-) No Task involved.

Comment: @QuanVN And if you really need a delay in the UI thread, don't run Thread.Sleep and Dispatcher.Invoke in a new Task. Just call `await Task.Delay(...)`.

Comment: Because I am new from async and await keyword so that  a little hardfor me :( Can you expain what is this

Comment: @QuanVN Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/